# How to know when I could reactivate HWP (Hardware PStates)

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules

I have a x1 carbon 4gen, and my computer hangs during boot on "HWP enabled" message. For now the solution is to disable HWP (Hardware PStates) with the option `intel_pstate=no_hwp` on boot.

There is a [commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/rafael/linux-pm.git/commit/?h=bleeding-edge&id=42341f87ba1bee4c5be95038c24abb69cbcf361a) in the linux kernel that fix this issue.

I'm running the `4.4.0-16-generic` kernel.

My question : How to know when I could reactivate HWP (Hardware PStates) ?
or what kernel version this patch will be applied ?

Comment: 4.6-rc2 mentioned at end of this ... https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110941